# error while devlake sonarqube connection setup

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I am setting up devlake for sonarqube. I have read and follwed the doc.

I have sonarqube hosted at : https://sonarqube.jam.com

**Getting this Error**: `error requesting https://sonarqube.jam.com/api/ Wraps: (2) Get "https://sonarqube.jam.com/api/": Service Unavailable Wraps: (3) Get "https://sonarqube.jam.com/api/" Wraps: (4) Service Unavailable Error types: (1) *hintdetail.withDetail (2) *hintdetail.withDetail (3) *url.Error (4) *errors.errorString`

[image]

seems like my api end point is not correct . from where can i get api endpoints ? or this error means something else ?